# Is this a UK visa refusal or a ban? What are the next steps?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, nigerian-citizens

This is a case of my spouse who was refused a study visa 15 years ago. He lost his passport which had his correct date of birth and which he used to apply for a visit visa; however, the reissued passport had a wrong date of birth which was used without correction before it was used for an application to the UK. This was in 2007.

We got married in 2019, and I wish to apply for a student visa. Can I still include him as my dependent? He has since used two passports with the correct date of birth, each to travel to South Africa.

Here's the text of the refusal letter (a [photo is also available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuQ1T.jpg)):

> The Entry Clearance Officer's decision:
> I have refused your visa
> application on this occasion because I am not satisfied, on the
> balance of probabilities, that you meet all the requirements of
> Section 41 of the Immigration Rules. This decision was made on the
> merits of this application. However, if you have a previous
> application and immigration history, this may have been considered.
>
> The Entry Clearance Officer's reasons and supporting evidence:
> You have applied for entry clearance to the United Kingdom as a family
> visitor. I have carefully considered your application on the basis of
> your passport, application form, and documents that you have provided.
> You have declared on your application form that the information you
> have given is complete and true to the best of your knowledge. It has
> not been necessary to interview you in order to reach a decision. In
> considering your application overall, I am not satisfied, on the
> balance of probabilities, that you meet the requirements of Paragraph
> 41 of the Immigration Rules HC395.
>
> In support of your application, you have submitted Nigerian passport
> no [redacted] in the identity of [redacted] (DOB: 26/03/73). You were
> previously refused a visa on 07/09/05 on passport [redacted] in the
> identity of [redacted] (DOB: 26/03/75). I am satisfied that your
> passport has been obtained by deception. You, therefore, do not hold a
> valid travel document and, as such, I am not satisfied of your
> nationality, identity, or previous immigration history. You,
> therefore, do not qualify to be granted entry clearance in accordance
> with Paragraph 320(iii) of HC395.
>
> Furthermore, your failure to disclose your previous application leads
> me to doubt that you are genuinely able and intend to study in the UK.
> Nor am I satisfied that you intend to leave the UK at the end of your
> proposed studies.
>
> I have impounded your passport and the document will be forwarded to
> the Nigerian Authorities.
>
> Further to the above, I cannot be satisfied, on the balance of
> probabilities, that you are related as claimed to the sponsor because
> you have produced no or insufficient evidence to substantiate your
> relationship to the sponsor. This raises doubts as to your true
> intentions and, as such, I am not satisfied that you have shown you
> meet the requirements of Paragraphs 41(i) and (ii) of HC395.
>
> Your application also falls to be refused under Paragraph 320 (21) of
> the Immigration Rules:
>
> i) Whether or not to the applicant's knowledge, a false document has
> been submitted in support of an application.

Comment: as always in these cases: contact your nearest embassy or consulate for the country in question.

Comment: And get the passport corrected.

Comment: Was he minor in 2007? Why he didn't mention about previous refusal of the visa? Or about the error in the name? No, I do not think he could immigrate as dependant. I think you should forget about UK for many more years (you could only worsen the situation).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi DOBs on the passport were 1975 and 1973, so not a minor.

Comment: If the refusal letter doesn’t specify a ban the typical result from such a refusal is a ban the *next time* an application is made. Given the time passed since 2007 *automatic* refusal of a new application and a ban might not apply https://www.davidsonmorris.com/general-grounds-for-refusal/  but in any event IMHO he/you should consult an immigration lawyer

Comment: I think i have a few red flags here. 1) refusal due to different identity. 2) failure to disclose previous application 3) his age 4) his country of origin